# Error Could not load type 'TrollMarket.web.MyRoleProvider.RoleSite'

Tags: c#, asp.net, role-manager

Like the title said there is an error with the roleManager

here's the web.config code:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyProvider" type="TrollMarket.web.MyRoleProvider.RoleSite"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

[Here's the file placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feeua.png)

here's GetRoleForUser

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) {
            AccountProvider accountProvider = new AccountProvider();
            string role = accountProvider.GetRole(username);
            string[] result = { role };
            return result;
        }
```

here is the getrole function

```
public string GetRole(string username) {
        var user = trollContext.Account.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.username == username);
        return user.role;
    }
```

please taught me how to fix it this is an assignment from my senior and with This error i couldn't get the role

this is the error

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TrollMarket.web.MyRoleProvider.RoleSite'.

Source Error:

Line 26:     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
Line 27:       <providers>
Line 28:         <add name="MyProvider" type="TrollMarket.web.MyRoleProvider.RoleSite"/>
Line 29:       </providers>
Line 30:     </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found the answer, for those who has the same problem check your provider namespace and change the type depending on the namespace like this

```
<add name="MyProvider" type="namespace.MyRoleProvider.RoleSite"/>
```